# How to avoid rerender in react when I use a hover effect

Tags: reactjs

I am designing an app in react and I am trying to implement a hover effect, I am using onMouseOver in an element, but i discovered that when that onMouseOver is triggered, it "rerenders" all the code of my component, which means that it declares again a vector that I declared as constant and ruins my functionality. Probably I am not understanding correctly react as I am noob on it. Do you know what could be the reason?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you are using DOM events like "mouseover" to toggle some "hover" state then yes, that component will rerender. Have you tried using CSS to apply hover styles? Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hover effect can be implemented using css pseudo hover class as well. Have your explored that angle?

Comment: The thing is that, that hover effect can't be done with css because it triggers some variable changes

Comment: You can separate out the CSS/visual effects from logical code updates. Sounds like the hover effect isn't your issue though. Please post your code so we're not guessing what the code we can't see is doing.

Comment: Please post a sample code here. So that we can help you.